# xcircuit: make user defined object (hit m key) doesn't give a pop-up dialog like the docs say

Tags: eda

I'm using xcircuit v3.10 rev 12 on arch linux. When I draw a new object and press the m key (or select edit-> make user object) the docs say I should get a popup dialog prompting me for a name.  Nothing comes up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ask at the forums of the EDA project?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that mouse button 2 select method (simulated by pressing both mouse buttons simultaneously and dragging) wasn't working on my laptop.  On a different computer it works fine, and by starting xcircuit with -2 it works as well. So, sorry for the noise....

Comment: Thank you for this useful info.